# Removing spaces with preg_replace outputs unrecognized characters in string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, pcre

i want to replace multiple spaces or `&nbsp;` with one space so i have tried below code using `preg_replace` function,

so it replaces spaces correctly but it also puts unrecognized characters in output string,

for demo i am taking `$string` variable but in actual it can be data from serverside database, see below code:

```
<?php 
     $string = "123080345&nbsp;900113760  165604100012";
     echo preg_replace("/(\s|&nbsp;)+/",' ',$string);

     //output: 123080345� 900113760� 165604100012
     //expected output: 123080345 900113760 165604100012
```

So my question is ***why preg_replace putting unrecognized characters and how to get clean and clear output***,

which doesn't have unrecognized characters as i have shown in above code as **expected output**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's just string with numbers, `spaces` and `&nbsp;`,

but i think in database it is **`UTF-8` encoded string** so when i have tried `preg_replace` it is returning unrecognized characters.

so it's working when i have tried **same regular expression with `/u` identifier for `unicode`**

so below is my solution:

```
<?php 

     $string = "123080345&nbsp;900113760  165604100012";
     echo preg_replace("/(\s|&nbsp;)+/u",' ',$string); //u for unicode characters 

     //output: 123080345 900113760 165604100012
```

i hope it can be helpful to someone, thanks.